# Returning a value based on Multiple Drop-Down Cells

Tags: excel

I've taken over a file, and want to have a "Current Status" cell auto-populate based on select drop-down cell choices. So if all the dropdowns are "N/A", I want to return a status of "N/A". If all are "Complete", return status "Complete". And then also mix: If some are "Complete" and some "In Progress", return "In Progress".

- If all are blank, returns blank
- All are Not-Started, returns Not-Started (ER1 in formula below)
- All are Complete, returns Complete (ER3 in formula below)
- All are N/A, returns N/A (ER4 in formula below)
- If any are marked In Progress/Complete/NA, returns In Progress (ER2 in formula below)

Our Current formula is this:

`=IF(AND(ISBLANK(DV4),ISBLANK(DW4),ISBLANK(DX4),ISBLANK(DY4),ISBLANK(DZ4),ISBLANK(EA4),ISBLANK(EB4),ISBLANK(EC4),ISBLANK(ED4),ISBLANK(EE4),ISBLANK(EF4),ISBLANK(EG4),ISBLANK(EH4),ISBLANK(EI4),ISBLANK(EJ4),ISBLANK(EK4),ISBLANK(EL4),ISBLANK(EM4),ISBLANK(EN4),ISBLANK(EO4))," ",IF(AND(DV4=$ER$3,DW4=$ER$3,DX4=$ER$3,DY4=$ER$3,DZ4=$ER$3,EA4=$ER$3,EB4=$ER$3,EC4=$ER$3,ED4=$ER$3,EE4=$ER$3,EF4=$ER$3,EG4=$ER$3,EH4=$ER$3,EI4=$ER$3,EJ4=$ER$3,EK4=$ER$3,EL4=$ER$3,EM4=$ER$3,EN4=$ER$3,EO4=$ER$3),"COMPLETE",IF(AND(DV4=$ER$4,DW4=$ER$4,DX4=$ER$4,DY4=$ER$4,DZ4=$ER$4,EA4=$ER$4,EB4=$ER$4,EC4=$ER$4,ED4=$ER$4,EE4=$ER$4,EF4=$ER$4,EG4=$ER$4,EH4=$ER$4,EI4=$ER$4,EJ4=$ER$4,EK4=$ER$4,EL4=$ER$4,EM4=$ER$4,EN4=$ER$4,EO4=$ER$4),"N/A",(IF(OR(DV4=$ER$2,DW4=$ER$2,DX4=$ER$2,DY4=$ER$2,DZ4=$ER$2,EA4=$ER$2,EB4=$ER$2,EC4=$ER$2,ED4=$ER$2,EE4=$ER$2,EF4=$ER$2,EG4=$ER$2,EH4=$ER$2,EI4=$ER$2,EJ4=$ER$2,EK4=$ER$2,EL4=$ER$2,EM4=$ER$2,EN4=$ER$2,EO4=$ER$2,DV4=$ER$3,DW4=$ER$3,DX4=$ER$3,DY4=$ER$3,DZ4=$ER$3,EA4=$ER$3,EB4=$ER$3,EC4=$ER$3,ED4=$ER$3,EE4=$ER$3,EF4=$ER$3,EG4=$ER$3,EH4=$ER$3,EI4=$ER$3,EJ4=$ER$3,EK4=$ER$3,EL4=$ER$3,EM4=$ER$3,EN4=$ER$3,EO4=$ER$3),"IN PROGRESS",IF(OR(DV4=$ER$1,DW4=$ER$1,DX4=$ER$1,DY4=$ER$1,DZ4=$ER$1,EA4=$ER$1,EB4=$ER$1,EC4=$ER$1,ED4=$ER$1,EE4=$ER$1,EF4=$ER$1,EG4=$ER$1,EH4=$ER$1,EI4=$ER$1,EJ4=$ER$1,EK4=$ER$1,EL4=$ER$1,EM4=$ER$1,EN4=$ER$1,EO4=$ER$1),"NOT STARTED","IN PROGRESS"))))))`

Which is working, but I want to make it cleaner and easier to change in the future. Rather than having to select each individual cell and make If/OR/AND statements for each one. I've tried using MATCH, but that seems to only count if 1 of the cells in the array is correct, rather than if they all Match. I thought maybe I could use EXACT and then a True/False with it, but Exact only seems to check 2 specific cells rather than a line. My googling led me to array formulas, but try as I might I couldn't get them to work. I thought it would work maybe to just use IF(A1:A9,) and complete the formula, but it doesn't seem to like that either.

Thank you

Edit:
Example Table
[image]

Comment: I suggest you post some sample data

Comment: I edited my post with an example table if that's what you meant?

Comment: I *think* this will do what you want: `=IF(COUNTIF(DV4:EO4,DV4)=20,DV4,IF(COUNTIF(DV4:EO4,"In Progress")>0,"In Progress",""))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will satisfy:

```
=IF(COUNTA(B2:F2)=0,"",IF(COUNTIF(B2:F2,B2)=COLUMNS(B2:F2),B2,"In Progress"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have worked for All Complete, Mixed Bag, and Blanks. How will I add in an "All N/A" portion?  

Just kidding! This is what I came up with and it seems to be working for the All N/A portion as well  

``=IF(COUNTA(B2:F2)=0," ",IF(COUNTIF(B2:F2,N1)=COLUMNS(B2:F2),N1,IF(COUNTIF(B2:F2,N4)=COLUMNS(B2:F2),N4,"In Progress")))``

Comment: Why are you changing the formula.  the `N#` should refer to the first cell in the range `B2` and you will not need the third `IF`

Comment: Sorry the way the actual file is set up has the different categories labeled off to the side and hidden so I was trying to recreate that to make sure it worked when I tried it on the real one. A coworker asked me to help them with this part so I'm just trying to get it to work with what they currently have set up.  Edit: I tried your formula on their file and it seems to work, so I was just making extra work for myself by trying to change it around!

Comment: Just did so. Thank you for your help. Just so I know for the future and understand how it all is working in excel: CountA part is checking for blank cells and if all are blank is returning blank. If(CountIf( part is checking all the cells and the value for the first cell (B2 in our example), and then =columns is checking if they are all the same value, and if so returning the value from B2, and "In Progress" is the "False" choice if the values don't all match?

Comment: `COLUMNS(B2:F2)` returns the number of columns, in this case `5` so if all the cells are the same `COUNTIF(B2:F2,B2)` would return `5` also and the criteria would be true and it will return the value in B2, if not there is a mismatch and it will return `In Progress`